# phpword crates file on windows but not on linux

Tags: permissions, phpword, pclzip

maybe anyone can help me.

For development I use XAMPP. Because I can use it in Office.
I worte some pages to crate docx-files. Using XAMPP they work.

Right system works on Linux. I copied my files in public_html an executet them. I got 500.
First I thaught reason is I use Lighty. So I purged it and installed Apache2.

Running my sites and scrips always I got error.

Last error is:
`[Sun Sep 24 20:25:10.629590 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 67571:tid 139740473879872] AH00489: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations [Sun Sep 24 20:25:10.629734 2023] [core:notice] [pid 67571:tid 139740473879872] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Sun Sep 24 20:25:19.399939 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 67575:tid 139740463191808] [client ::1:41902] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /home/wolftilmann/public_html/haushalt/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php on line 171PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Exception\\Exception: Could not close zip file text.docx:  in /home/wolftilmann/public_html/haushalt/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php:172\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/wolftilmann/public_html/haushalt/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/Word2007.php(143): PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Shared\\ZipArchive->close()\n#1 /home/wolftilmann/public_html/haushalt/003_beleg/319.php(235): PhpOffice\\PhpWord\\Writer\\Word2007->save()\n#2 /home/wolftilmann/public_html/haushalt/beleg.php(23): include('/home/wolftilmann/p...')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /home/wolftilmann/public_html/haushalt/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Shared/ZipArchive.php on line 172', referer: http://localhost/~wolftilmann/haushalt/index2.php`

on /tmp always Apache2 creates direcory like this:
`www-data www-data 4,0K 24. Sep 19:51 PHPWordWriter_6510772258d5a6.16228120`

Trying save file does not work
Trying offer file for download does not work.

/tmp has 1777.

Could anyone help me please?

THX
Wolf-Tilmann
`

Right system works on Linux. I copied my files in public_html an executet them. I got 500.
First I thaught reason is I use Lighty. So I purged it and installed Apache2.

Installed Apache more than 5 times.

Pclzip is installed